# Is there a way to group css attributes using tailwindcss?

Tags: tailwind-css

For example, rather than writing hover:text-16 hover:color-blue-200

to just do:

hover:[text-16 color-blue-200]

to reduce the code's bulkiness and avoid accidental errors, since attributes will either be in they're correct 'state' or not, as opposed to it needing to be defined every time.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no such feature in Tailwind. There have been many suggestions and feature requests about adding such a feature (such as in their GitHub discussions). The maintainers have addressed this request before, that you may wish to read up on if you have not already done so:

- [A Twitter thread from the creator of Tailwind, Adam Wathan](https://twitter.com/adamwathan/status/1461519820411789314):

  > So the takeaway here is that although the grouped syntax *looks* like less code when you're authoring it, it actually creates both a bigger CSS file *and* a bigger HTML file in production, making it a very black and white performance anti-pattern.
- [A previous GitHub discussion thread with maintainer responses](https://github.com/tailwindlabs/tailwindcss/discussions/8337#discussioncomment-4032611)

Comment: This solution is perfect, the links tell me everything there is to know. Thank you.